# How to form a proper if else in make to find user?

Tags: bash, makefile

I am very new to make and have wanted to learn more about conditionals.

I want to check the result of whoami in a makefile but keep getting errors

```
ifeq ($(whoami), "John")
echo "PC"
else 
echo "Server"
endif
```

Here it gives me an error on the line echo "Server" saying *** missing separator how do I fix it?

Comment: bash doesn't user ifeq or endif. Please refer to the documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Comment: Removed `cmake` tag because it is irrelevant.

Comment: What language is this supposed to be? It looks neither like bash nor like a makefile. Specify how you invoke this program.

Comment: To be clear, `$(whoami)` epands the make variable `whoami` which presumably was never set to anything.  It won't run the command `whoami`.  Secondly, you should not include quotes in your comparison: quotes are not special to make so they will be included in the match.  Unless your username is actually `"John"` (including the quotes) it will never match.

Comment: It was in reference to a makefile, CJW's EDIT portion solved this perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(whoami) == "John" ]]; then
  echo "PC"
else
  echo "Server"
fi
```

As mentioned by Primitive, bash does not use `ifeq` and `endif`.

**EDIT**

As per chepner's comment, this question could be about Make and not Bash, in that case, this should work:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

USER = $(shell whoami)

buildbegin:
ifeq ($(USER), John)
        @echo PC
else
        @echo Server
endif
```

Can be tested with `make -f $MakeFile`

Comment: `make` itself has its own `if` statement; it's not clear which the OP actually wants to use.

Comment: The answer above worked perfectly. It was about make, I knew there was a way to get the result of the shell into a variable i was just missing the $(shell whoami). Thanks for the help!